# How can I synchronize client's timestamp with "firestore" timestamp?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making an online game. The users must see a perfectly matching countdown timer. I am using firebase and firestore for database. I was going to make a document and update field per 1 second, while users are getting real-time update through .onSnapshot javascript function. However it didn't work well, 'cause updating the field didn't occur by 1 second. I was tried to fix it through node-cron, if user gets an updated timestamp, during 30 seconds users will decrease the timer with node-cron and get another updated timestamp. However users' countdown timer didn't match about 1 second. I am using python server, and would like to use cloud functions too.

I found firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now() function, but I am worried if this function is getting timestamp from local time. Also, I tested with two laptops but their time didn't match either by 1 second.

Thank you very much.